# Matching prefixes for list of words with mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard, string-matching

My goal is to avoid queries that tries to match wildcards because it is X100 times slower than queries that match prefix with a wildcard followed.

For a single word it is not a problem, but what if i have list of words separated by a comma?

Is there any efficient way to match those words by prefix (with a wild card that follows) and not by wildcard only?

I mean is there any way to avoid matching pattern like %word% in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presumption is that you have an index on the list.  Otherwise, the performance of the `like` should not be 100 times slower with a prefix match versus a non-prefix match.  Yes, somewhat slower.  But most of the effort should be reading the data from the pages.

If you have a list of words separated by a comma, then you have the wrong data structure.  You need to introduce a new table with an id and each word.

Once you have the data properly normalized, you can use proper relational constructs for your query, and dispense with using `like` for joining tables or finding elements.

Comment: You are right, i am using indexes. And you are right again with the solution. I will accept your answer in 9 minutes :)